# Error while installing @capactitor/cli with ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

Im getting the following error.
while running `npm i -D -E @capacitor/cli`

```
npm verb stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...FCnINK8IxATDi2WfhWMRD'
npm verb stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
npm verb stack     at parseJson (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
npm verb stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:96:50
npm verb stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

I have following softwares installed

```
Node : v12.12.0
Npm : v6.13.0
Ionic : v6.10.2
```

Please help me debug the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently i was running into trouble because of npm cache.
As of npm@5 the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid.
So i had to force clean the npm cache using `npm cache clean --force`,  and it worked